# Generic bidimensional array

Tags: c

I want to create a bidimensional array like so:

```
void **mdeclaraMatrice(int nrLini,int nrColoane, int sizeOfElement)
{
    int i;
    void **m = malloc(nrLini * 4);
    if(m==NULL)
        return NULL;
    for(i=0; i<nrLini; i++)
    {
        *(m + (i*4)) = malloc(nrColoane * sizeOfElement);
        if(*(m + (i*4)) == NULL)
             return NULL;
    }
    return m;
}
```

I whant to use it like this:

```
int **m = (int **)mdeclaraMatrice(n,m,sizeof(int));
```

but it doesn't work. What do I do wrong?

Comment: `*(m + (i*4))` is not correct. use pointer arithmetic on defined data types.

Comment: why? m is a pointer-to-pointer so pointer arithmetics should work

Comment: @barakmanos `sizeof(void *) = 4` 
@SouravGhosh can you give me an example?

Comment: @Tandura: `sizeof(void*) == 4` only on 32-bit platforms.

Comment: All `int` (in the 1st snippet) shall be `size_t`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `m[i]` instead of `*(m+i*4)` and let the compiler do the arithmetic.

In addition, you should deallocate the already-allocated memory in case of a failure.

**Try this instead:**

```
void **mdeclaraMatrice(int nrLini, int nrColoane, int sizeOfElement)
{
    int i;
    void **m = malloc(nrLini * sizeof(void*));
    if (m == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (i=0; i<nrLini; i++)
    {
        m[i] = malloc(nrColoane * sizeOfElement);
        if (m[i] == NULL)
        {
             while (i-- > 0)
                 free(m[i]);
             free(m);
             return NULL;
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: @alk: My mistake, I thought OP wanted an array of 4 elements (didn't realize that he/she meant `sizeof(void*)`). Now fixed, thanks.

Comment: Nitpicking: `int i` shall be `size_t i`; Instead `void **m = malloc(nrLini * sizeof(void*));` a more roboust coding would be `void ** m = malloc(nrLini * sizeof *m));`

Comment: @alk: I agree about using `*m` instead of `void*` because it makes it easier to change the type of `m`. But it also makes the code less readable due to the "large number of *s", so I usually opt to use the type instead (even if it makes the task of changing it slightly more difficult).

Comment: How does `*(m + (i*4))` differ from `m[4*i]`? The issue lies within the fact that `4` multiplicator is unnecessary. In other words while `m[i]` is correct form and I agree with that, `*(m + i)` would be acceptable too (I didn't downvote though).

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski: You are absolutely correct. I've confused `void**` with `void*`, where the use of pointer arithmetic would not compile. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[not an answer to the question, but to the indented usage of the proper answer as given by others]

To access the `void` pointer array as an array of `int`, doing this

```
int **m = (int **)mdeclaraMatrice(n,m,sizeof(int));
```

is not correct, as per the C-Standard only `void*` converts to any other pointer properly, `void**` doesn't necessarily. So it shall correctly be

```
void ** ppv = mdeclaraMatrice(n,m,sizeof(int));
int * pi = *ppv;  /* Please note, there is NO casting necessary here! */
```

Then access the members like so:

```
pi[0] = 42  
pi[1] = 43; 
...
```

Which essently is the same as doing

```
*((int *) (pi + 0)) = 42;
*((int *) (pi + 1)) = 43;
```

which indeed does not make sense really as `pi` already is `int*`, so the fully correct approach (also taking into account the 2nd dimension) would be:

```
((int *)(ppv[0]))[0] = 42;
((int *)(ppv[0]))[1] = 43;
```

Which could be made usable by definging a macro:

```
#define GENERIC_ARRAY_ELEMENT(type, address, r, c) \
  ((type *)(address[r]))[c] 

GENERIC_ARRAY_ELEMENT(int, ppv, 0, 0) = 42;
GENERIC_ARRAY_ELEMENT(int, ppv, 0, 1) = 43;
```

Comment: Did you mean `pi[0] = i; pi[1] = j;` Inner array is allocated.

Comment: Yes sure, re-corrected again ... :-S had been lost in the multiple indirections ... @2501

Comment: You can do `(( int* )ppv[i])[j] = 12345 ;` if you don't want to copy.

Comment: Ya, I was thinking this. Looks terribile however ... ;-) @2501

Comment: That is why you copy, stack mem for a few pointers doesn't really matter. ( Or allocate an additional void* inside ppv for the int** array :) using one malloc alltogether )

Answer (score 3):

I will address the problem of allocation an array of void pointers and then interpreting them as an array of int pointers.

```
int **nope = (int **)mdeclaraMatrice(n,m,sizeof(int));
```

Even assuming the allocation was completely correct the assignment and later usage of `nope` is undefined behavior. `void**` and `int**` have incompatible types.

What you can do is the following. Assign the void pointers one by one to an array of int pointers.

```
void** arrp = mdeclaraMatrice(n,m,sizeof(int));
int* arr[n] ;
for( size_t i = 0 , i < n ; i++ )
    arr[i] = arrp[i] ;
```

And then use the `arr` array, When you want to free the memory you free the original pointer:

```
free( arrp ) ;
```

Comment: Would this copying really be necessary? See my update answer on why I doubt this.

Comment: Yes, definitely( or walk trough the void** array and cast to int* every time manually ). You seem to only use the first array and `*((int *) (pi + 0)) = 42;` doesn't make much sense since pi is already int*.

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs in this line:

```
*(m + (i*4)) = malloc(nrColoane * sizeOfElement);
```

You have to know that when adding a number to an address, the address will be incremented by the number **times** the size of the object the address points to. So if your pointer points to an object that is of size 4 bytes, and you add 1 to it, then the address will automatically be incremented by 4, **not** by 1. So you should abandon `*4`.

Also, use the `sizeof` operator when allocating space, because addresses (and thus pointers) can have different sizes on different processor architectures.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't even need your generic 2D array function if you know the powerfull VLA features of C99. To allocate a true 2D array (no index array required), you just do this:

```
int (*twoDIntArray)[width] = malloc(height*sizeof(*twoDIntArray));
```

That's it. Accesses are just as simple:

```
twoDIntArray[line][column] = 42;
```

In this code, `twoDIntArray` is a pointer to an array of `width` integers. The `malloc()` call simply allocates enough space for `height` such line arrays. When you do the pointer arithmetic `twoDIntArray[line]`, you add the size of `line` line arrays to the pointer, which produces the address of the corresponding line array. This line array is then indexed by the second array subscript `[column]`.

Needless to say that freeing such an array is just as trivial:

```
free(twoDIntArray);
```